# SQLException: JZ0S4: Cannot execute an empty (zero-length) query. on a Prepared Statement

Tags: java, sqlexception, prepared-statement

Heres a class executing PreparedStatements on a Connection.

```
public class doSomething {
    private PreparedStatement ps;

    public setPS (Connection conn) throws SQLException {
        String sql = "select * from table where id = ?";
        ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    }

    public void runSomething(String var){
        ps.setString(1,var);
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        ...
    }
}
```

I call

```
doSomethingInstance.setPS(conn);
doSomethingInstance.runSomething(var);
```

from another class and this throws and exception at the

```
 ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

The exception is SQLException: JZ0S4: Cannot execute an empty (zero-length) query. on a Prepared Statement. I cant understand why. Does anyone see what Iam doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: very strange... if the statement was really empty, setString() should not work first. Are you sure that is the correct/complete code? ("public setPS(..." should not compile: missing return type). DOn't know what database you are using, but "table" is not a very good name for a table, it's a reserved keyword (MySQL at least).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been fixed folks. There was a problem with the database permissions. Catching and printing the stacktrace on

```
 ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

indicated that the table being accessed by the query was not found. I still have to figure out why the SQLException: JZ0S4: Cannot execute an empty (zero-length) query is being thrown.

Thanks for your time and consideration.
Rohan

Answer (score 1):

Go back and copy the code straight from your source file, then edit your question. You have a potential ambiguity: Your first fragment calls the prepared statement "preparedStatement", then you change to "prepareStatement" (without the "d"). Having a clean look at your source code will make isolating the problem easier. Do you have two variables or did you mistype your example?

[later...]
Thanks for updating your code. I'm not seeing an obvious problem with it. Have you stepped through it with a debugger (e.g., in Eclipse) to ensure that the two methods are being called as expected?

Comment: I apologize. I have fixed the object name. It is basically the same PreparedStatment handle being used by both the methods.

Answer (score 0):

can you print the contents of sql before executing the query? I suspect it's losing it's contents

Comment: @rohangter: I don't know this API, but are you running a different query than you prepared?

Answer (score 0):

Is **var** non null? Is **var** of the correct type(int instead of String I would think?)